# How do I Run a Workbook_Open code only during the weekdays? (M-F)

Tags: excel, vba, weekday

I have a series of Application.OnTime codes that need ran on specific days throughout the week (M-F). I don't need these codes to run on Saturday/Sunday. How do I code in to only run M-F?  The Application.OnKey codes need to run every day.
Thank you

````
    'Set keyboard shortcuts
    Application.OnKey "^+{UP}", "Sheet4.SpinButton1_SpinDown"
    Application.OnKey "^+{DOWN}", "Sheet4.SpinButton1_SpinUp"
    
    If Weekday(Now()) > 2 And Weekday(Now()) < 7 Then Call Workbook_Open
    
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:15:00"), "Saveit"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:17:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:33:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:59:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:21:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:45:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:03:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:23:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:41:00"), "MASTER"

End Sub```
````

Comment: Uh, what did you try?  I assumed you tried to check the day of the week and had a problem.  What code did you use to check that, and what problem did you run into?

Comment: ```Sub SecondSub()
    If Weekday(Now()) > 2 And Weekday(Now()) < 7 Then Call Workbook_Open
End Sub```

Comment: I'd put it within the `Workbook_Open` sub, bracketing the `.OnTime` functions.

Comment: I am confused as to what you mean for bracketing the .OnTime Function. I updated my code in the question

Comment: Remove `call workbook_open` and put `end if` after those lines you want to run on weekdays only.

Comment: I have assumed your code above is in the `workbook_open` routine.  If not, it probably should be. `call workbook_open` doesn't make much sense to me as that routine will have run already when the workbook opened.  What were you trying to accomplish with that call?

Comment: I have been trying about everything, I just tried to have the macro call itself to see if it would work. I have no idea how to make this work and anything to help make it work would be great help

Comment: Does your code run OK, upon workbook open, without the check for day of week?

Comment: Yes the code works perfectly whenever I don't have the "If" Statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is working OK without the `IF`, then what I suggested in the comments should work.

Is this how you modified your code in response to my comments?

*I used `Date` instead of `Now` but they should give the same results.  Also the `()` after the `Now` are not needed in VBA*

*I also used `>=2` since you indicated M-F, i.e: you wanted to **include** Monday*

```
...
'Set keyboard shortcuts
    Application.OnKey "^+{UP}", "Sheet4.SpinButton1_SpinDown"
    Application.OnKey "^+{DOWN}", "Sheet4.SpinButton1_SpinUp"
    
If Weekday(Date) >= 2 And Weekday(Date) < 7 Then 
    
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:15:00"), "Saveit"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:17:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:33:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:59:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:21:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:45:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:03:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:23:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:41:00"), "MASTER"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Since this is on Workbook_Open will I have to open this file every day for the code to reset itself? Thank you

Comment: With the testing that I have done so far with this code, it should be good to go. Thank you again @Ron

Comment: @ANDANDAND Workbook_Open will only fire when the workbook opens. For various methods of running this on a schedule, take a look at [VBA for smarties: Application.OnTime](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Application.OnTime_en.html)